# Ability to Interface with an LTSpice virtual circuit with Java or other software language

Tags: java

I am working on a project with some EEs who are designing a circuit that will have some programmable logic.  They are modeling this circuit in LTSpice.  I will be designing a GUI to be the control interface for this circuit once it is actually a proper circuit.  I was wondering if there is some way that I could "talk" to the LTspice circuit using Java or another programming language so that I could get a head start on designing my GUI and control backend.

Comment: Is this the [LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice) you're taking about?

Comment: There is a user group at (http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/LTspice/) - they may be able to help you. For Verilog simulations I was able to do something like what you want using sockets, but searches for LTSpice and sockets only get me electrical sockets, not software sockets.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check them out.